# how to choose the openstack version（like Juno/kilo/liberty) using the autopilot

Tags: software-installation, openstack, openstack-autopilot

i installed ubuntu openstack with the autopilot.When i run the command

`sudo openstack-install`

it looks like the openstack vertion is liberty.So, my question is that how can i choose version of openstack to install?

Answer (score 1):

The autopilot only allows installation of the most recent qualified openstack release.  Right now, liberty is what is shipped, but soon it will be mitaka.  At that point, liberty will no longer be an option, and so-on.